# Circular Permutation with repetition

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

In how many **distinct** ways, can $k$ distinct types of objects be placed around a circular table, with $n$ empty spaces to be filled?
It is given that there are **infinitely many** number of objects for each type, hence repetition of the objects is allowed.

Edit: Two arrangements are considered distinct, if rotating either of the arrangements does not yield the other one.

Comment: Just treat this as you would any other burnsides lemma problem with the following modification... treat the unused spaces as a $k+1$'st type of object.

Comment: Up to rotations? Rotations + reflections?

Comment: It’s hard to be certain what the question is. You say you are placing $k$ distinct objects around a circular table with $n$ spaces, but you don’t say how many types of objects there are. I suspect you are placing $n$ (not $k$) objects around the table, filling all available spaces, and doing this with $k$ different types of objects. You might get more feedback if the question is clearer and certainly if you show what you have tried to do so far.

Comment: @SteveKass Thank you for pointing that out. I've edited the question.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Upto Rotations only